# Bit level operations in Java

Tags: java, bit

I'm trying to make some bit operations in Java for applying masks, represent sets etc.
Why:

```
int one=1;
int two=2;
int andop=1&2;
System.out.println(andop);
```

Prints a "0" when is supposed to be "3":

```
0...001
0...010
_______
0...011
```

And how can I get that behavior?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you know, that Java has a specific class for this: [BitSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the binary 'or' operator:

```
int andop = 1 | 2;
```

The binary 'and' operator will leave bits sets that are in both sides; in the case of `1` and `2` that is no bits at all.

Answer (score 10):

You mixed up bitwise OR and bitwise AND

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for a bitwise "OR", not "AND":

```
int both = one | two;
```

"OR" says: "bit *n* should be 1 if it's 1 in input *x* *or* it's 1 in input *y*"

"AND" says: "bit *n* should be 1 if it's 1 in input *x* *and* it's 1 in input *y*"

Answer (score 2):

& must be both 1

```
0...001
&...&&&
0...010
_______
0...000
```

answer = 0
| is or ,one 1 is OK

```
0...001
|...|||
0...010
_______
0...011
```

answer = 3

Answer (score 0):

Better solution is to use *enums* with *int* values *ONE(1), TWO(2)* etc, and [EnumSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html).

From JavaDoc:

> Enum sets are represented internally as **bit vectors**. This
>   representation is extremely compact and efficient. The space and time
>   performance of this class should be good enough to allow its use as a
>   **high-quality, typesafe alternative to traditional int-based "bit
>   flags**."